# C++ displaying an image with SDL2 with different formats than .bmp

Tags: c++, graphics, sdl-2

I am trying to display an image in SDL2 and the only guide I found was a guide about how to display a .bmp image. What I would like to do is displaying an image or setting a temporary image as a background. For example if I press LEFT_KEY the program should proceed to the next image. Any relevant guides or any examples you can share? It is not needed to set the image as a background (stretched), my goal is to display an image and being able to scroll through other images by pressing a key.

Comment: there is a plugin library called 'SDL_image' for this purpose

Comment: Yes thank you! I just needed a good guide for the library!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use SDL_Image:

https://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_image/

Example:

[Loading PNGs with SDL_image](http://lazyfoo.net/tutorials/SDL/06_extension_libraries_and_loading_other_image_formats/index2.php)

Comment: Thank you very much sir!

Comment: I will, just need to wait 10 minutes before setting it as an answer.